# My 5th marker is not showing up, whats the problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

My 4th marker is not showing up and I can't seem to find the problem.
I checked if the variable names were correct, I checked the syntax and I even changed the position variables to see if that would change anything. The map loads but it don't show more than 3 markers.

Heres my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>

<style>

    #map {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

    function initMap() {

// Markers position
var pos = {lat: 38.64971527, lng: -9.143150};
var pos1 = {lat: 38.628753, lng: -9.115710};
var pos2 = {lat: 38.61512, lng: -9.110663};
var pos3 = {lat: 38.615125, lng: -9.110663};

// Map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: 38.628753, lng: -9.115710}
        });
        
//Markers
   var Mark = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pos,
  map: map,
});

 var Mark1 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pos1,
  map: map,
});

  var Mark3 = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: pos2,
   map: map,
});
  var Marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: pos3,
   map: map,
});

}
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You should remove your API key from this

Comment: It's a test key, there shouldn't be a problem with that, I removed anyways.

Edit: I just put the key that I found in the Google API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the markers **are** there. At your zoom level, markers for `pos2` and `pos3` are so close that they overlap. You can see both if you zoom in using the map zoom/mousewheel.

Comment: I'm going to check it.

Edit: I just checked and there is no markers on top of each other.

Comment: It was the lower-right marker(s); both appeared to be in the same building/structure on the map.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb right now, thanks Ito, the problems were the coordinates, I added one number and that's why some marker didn't show up and I also had one that was too near with another. I was focusing too much on other stuff such as syntax errors etc..